# Arduino due temperature reading shows random temperatures

Tags: sensors, arduino-due, sram

I am using an Arduino Due board to read three temperatures from three separate smt160-30 digital sensors but the program is behaving very randomly. the code I am using is one I got from arduino official site and changed the structure to get three temp readings and display them on a 16x2 lcd. The problem is when I use one sensor the output is reasonable but when I use all three the temperature showing are all off by 4 degrees. also I tried removing the line `lcd.print(temperature1, 1)` and the output temperatures changed. Is this odd behavior because of SRAM issues ? if so how can I find out about it and fix it ?

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

unsigned long now;
unsigned long lastSample;
unsigned int sampleSize;

unsigned int highCount1;
unsigned int highCount2;
unsigned int highCount3;

unsigned long lastOutput;

float temperature1;
float temperature2;
float temperature3;
float hcf1, hcf2, hcf3;
float ssf;

int sensorPin1 = 23;
int sensorPin2 = 24;
int sensorPin3 = 26;

void setup(){

    pinMode(sensorPin1, INPUT);
    pinMode(sensorPin2, INPUT);
    pinMode(sensorPin3, INPUT);

    digitalWrite(sensorPin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(sensorPin2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(sensorPin3, LOW);

    lastSample = 0;
    sampleSize = 0;

    highCount1 = 0;
    highCount2 = 0;
    highCount3 = 0;

    temperature1 = 0;
    temperature2 = 0;
    temperature3 = 0;

    lastOutput = 0;

    delay(2000);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);

}

void loop() {
    now = micros();
    if (now - lastOutput > 3000000) {
        lcd.clear();

        hcf1 = highCount1;
        hcf2 = highCount2;
        hcf3 = highCount3;

        ssf = sampleSize;

        temperature1 = ((hcf1 / ssf) -0.32)/0.0047;
        temperature2 = ((hcf2 / ssf) -0.32)/0.0047;
        temperature3 = ((hcf3 / ssf) -0.32)/0.0047;

        lastOutput = now;
        sampleSize = 0;

        highCount1 = 0;
        highCount2 = 0;
        highCount3 = 0;


        lcd.print(temperature1, 1);
        lcd.print(" ");

        lcd.print(temperature2, 1);
        lcd.print(" ");

        lcd.print(temperature3, 1);

    }
    if (now - lastSample > 50) {
        sampleSize++;
        highCount1 = highCount1 + digitalRead(sensorPin1);
        highCount2 = highCount2 + digitalRead(sensorPin2);
        highCount3 = highCount3 + digitalRead(sensorPin3);
        lastSample = now;
    } else {
        delayMicroseconds(10);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Did you read about this smt160 sensor ? It relies on the calculation of duty cycle of the square wave output from the sensor, to calculate the temparature.

> **temperature = (dutyCycle) -0.32)/0.0047**

The square wave output has to be sampled at 8KHz or at 125us for no loss of information. This block samples that data.

> if (now - lastSample > 50) {
>
> sampleSize++;
>
> highCount1 = highCount1 + digitalRead(sensorPin1);
>
> highCount2 = highCount2 + digitalRead(sensorPin2);
>
> highCount3 = highCount3 + digitalRead(sensorPin3);
>
> lastSample = now;
>       }
>
> else {
>           delayMicroseconds(10);
>       }

when you increased the number of code lines , information loss also increased, cz more number of instructions have to be executed now , till reaching the corresponding digital reads.

Comment: So if I put it in a for loop to guarantee the needed sample it should work right ? is there better way to do this ? thank you for responding

Comment: I don't think so. This is already running in loop under void loop(). So It may still have the same problem.

Comment: One solution is to shift the start of sampling of three sensors. Divide the time frame into 3 parts. First time frame only for sampling and displaying the temp of sensor 1, second one only for second sensor, first sensor would be idle. Like that. But the temperature update interval will increase.

Comment: I don't understand how to divide it into different time frames. Is it possible to create a function for getting temperature and call it three times for each sensor ? if so how do I write the function where is the exit point of it ?

Comment: You have to code some logic using if conditions and  a variable to keep track of time passed. Based on the value of that variable , call functions for processing sensor 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: I ran the code for 1 sensor without any adding additional code and the temp seemed to be stable and pretty accurate with a sampleSize of 31600 so I wrote this function with 31600 sample rate with 10 microsecond intervals and it does work can I just go with this ?

Comment: float GetTemp(int pinN){
      for(int i =0; i < 31600; i++){
        highDuration = highDuration + digitalRead(pinN);
        delayMicroseconds(50);
      }
      hcf = highDuration;
      dutyCycle = highDuration / (float) 31600;
      temp = (dutyCycle - 0.32)/0.0047;
      highDuration = 0;
      return temp;
    }

Comment: yea if this worked, you can write the same function for the next two sensors too...And just call this function one by one from the main code